# Assuming `obj` has type `objtype`, are `super(cls,obj)` and `super(cls,objtype)` the same?

Tags: python, python-3.x, singleton, super

In Python, assuming that `obj` has type `objtype`, are `super(cls,obj)` and `super(cls,objtype)` the same?

Is it correct that `super(cls,obj)` converts `obj` to another object whose class is a superclass of `objtype` which is after `cls` in the MRO of `objtype`?

What does `super(cls,objtype)` mean then?

---

For example, given an implementation of the Singleton design pattern:

```
class Singleton(object):
    _singletons = {}
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwds):
        if cls not in cls._singletons:
            cls._singletons[cls] = super(Singleton, cls).__new__(cls)
        return cls._singletons[cls]
```

any subclass of  `Singleton`  (that does not further override  `__new__` ) has exactly one instance.

What does `super(Singleton, cls)` mean, where `cls` is a class? What does it return?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super), `super`

> Return a proxy object that delegates method calls to a parent or sibling class of type.

So `super` returns an object which knows how to call the methods of other classes in the class hierarchy.

The second argument to `super` is the object to which `super` is bound; generally this is an instance of the class, but if `super` is being called in the context of a method that is a  classmethod or staticmethod then we want to call the method on the class object itself rather than an instance.

So calling `super(SomeClass, cls).some_method()` means call `some_method` on the *classes* that `SomeClass` descends from, rather than on *instances* of these classes.  Otherwise `super` calls behave just like a `super` call in an instance method.

The usage looks more natural in less complicated code:

```
class C(SomeBaseClass):

    def method(self):
        # bind super to 'self'
        super(C, self).method()

    @classmethod
    def cmethod(cls):
        # no 'self' here -- bind to cls
        super(C, cls).cmethod()
```

Note that `super(C, cls)` is required in python2, but an empty `super()` is enough in python3.

In your singleton example, `super(Singleton, cls).__new__(cls)` returns the result of calling `object.__new__(cls)`, an instance of `Singleton`.  It's being created this way to avoid recursively calling `Singleton.__new__`.