# Why do we provide the object as an argument to super()?

Tags: python

In the python docs, one can read the following about `super()`:

> If the second argument is omitted, the super object returned is
>   unbound.

They are referring to the second argument in `super(class_name, second_argument)`. What does it mean for an object to be unbound? I've heard of unbound methods, meaning they don't exist on any object, but on a class (please correct me if I'm wrong), but what is an unbound object?

Here is a code example provided in the same docs. It shows a typical call to `super()` in order to get the overridden method of the superclass.

```
class C(B):
    def method(self, arg):
        super(C, self).method(arg)
```

As you can see, they do use the second argument here. Why should we do that? What would happen if we didn't?

EDIT: I tried the following...

```
class B(object):
    def method(self, arg):
        print(arg)

class C(B):
    def method(self, arg):
        super(C, self).method(arg)

class D(B):
    def method(self, arg):
        super(D).method(arg)

c = C()
d = D()

c.method("hi")
d.method("hi again")
```

The call to `c.method()` worked fine, printing "hi", but the second call, to `d.method()`, crashed:

```
n132-p95:Desktop sahandzarrinkoub$ python2 super.py
hi
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "super.py", line 17, in <module>
    d.method("hi again")
  File "super.py", line 11, in method
    super(D).method(arg)
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'method'
```

Comment: Try without using the second argument... then you tell us what would happen  :)

Comment: This is answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super-with-init-methods

Comment: `dir(super(D))` might give you insight into what attributes it does have

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/46190217/5320906